# Languages without built-in support for constants

Tags: python, perl

Why does neither Perl nor Python have support for constants? Is it just considered a marginal feature that just no one meant to implement, or is there maybe something more behind it?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html

Comment: good to know but that's not built into the language right?

Comment: @zedoo, Yes it is, complete with compile-time inlining.

Comment: In addition to the use constants pragma, you can also use the Readonly  [link](http://search.cpan.org/~roode/Readonly-1.03/Readonly.pm). There's a case for preferring this over `constants` (in Perl Best Practices) but it does run slower.

Answer (score 6):

Python doesn't support constants because the idea is against its philosophy: **we're all consenting adults here**. That is, Python doesn't forbid changing things through the software; instead, it merely indicates that you shouldn't change things and may stop working if you do.

To indicate a constant in a Python script one normally makes it a module-level variable in ALL_CAPS.

(Another common example is 'private' members of a class, normally marked with a single leading underscore, which are private only by convention and work the same as ordinary attributes.)

Comment: Seriously not trolling but the whole whitespace thing doesn't seem like Python's philosophy is that we are all consenting adults.

Comment: @musiKk: For not trolling, you do seem to be trolling :)

Comment: @ysth: I'm looking at this from a language philosophical standpoint. As a Perl fan I have no problems admitting that Perl can be a garbled mess of punctuation characters sometimes (although I avoid it if possible). But I also don't think you should imply that a language treats you like an adult that can decide how you write something if it imposes such huge constraints in formatting.

Comment: @musiKk: the whitespace is purely a syntactic thing. The semantics of the language are liberating.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a variable or value as constant similar to any other languages (like JAVA or C). Just don't change it.

You can differentiate normal and Constant variables by using proper naming conventions.
i.e declare the constant as all caps

```
class Foo(object):
  CONST_NAME = "Name"

#or just
CONST_NAME = "Name"
```

though, if you need constants to be work on python. this links [Constants in Python](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/), [Constants](http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/108), would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Create a "constants" class in Perl or Python, keeping your constants in this class. Import the class in your Perl or Python script.

Comment: At least in Python, that doesn't make them constant.

Comment: @katrielalex, there are ways of disallowing assignment to something that looks like a data member, so what @Alex says is possible. But is it pythonic? I'd say not.

Comment: @juancho: ish, not for certain. (There are many hacks that spring to mind to get around e.g. the lack of a setter on a property.)